# How to change the color only the clicked element of many iterated dynamic elements

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm trying to change the background color of dynamic html elements (`span`) to be red when user clicks them.

```
function showQuestion(){
    for(let i = 0; i < QuesPartA.length; i++){
      $(".questionBox").append('<div class="Question">Number '+ parseInt(i+1) +'</div>');
      QuesPartA[i]['option'].forEach(option => {
          $(".questionBox").append('<span class="pilihan">'+option +' </span><br>');  
      });
  } 

$(".secondBox").append('<a href="Listening Part A.html" class="btnToPartB">Continue to Part B</a>');
  };
```

But I want only the one clicked that changes color, not all `span.pilihan`. I have tried some ways, but it ended up either changing all `span`s to be red or not changing at all. Any ideas how to do it effectively?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use jQuery events to get the element of click.
Like below:

```js
$(() => {
 generateQuestion(1);
});

var q = 1;

function generateQuestion(num) {
  var question = document.createElement("span");
  question.innerHTML = "Question " + num;
  document.body.append(question);
}

$("body").on("click", "span", function(){
  $(this).css("background", "red");
  q++;
  generateQuestion(q);
});
```

```css
span {
cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Edit: now delegate

Comment: Thanks, it works!